# Confused about this definition of limit superior.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

The definition I am given is as follows:  Let $(x_n)$ be a real valued sequence.  For each positive integer $n$, let $s_n:=\sup\{x_m:m\geq n\}$.  If $(s_n)$ converges, we denote its limit by $\overline{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}}x_n$ and call it the limit superior of $(x_n)$.

Now I am to prove that the limit superior of a real valued sequence exists if and only if the sequence is bounded above.

I understand that if the sequence is $\textit{not}$ bounded above the the limit superior will not exist, since there is no supremum of the tail of the sequence.

But as far as the other direction goes, I assume that the sequence is bounded above.  But what if it is not bounded below?  For example, what if $(x_n)=(-1,-2,-3,-4,...)$.  Then, if my understanding is right, we should have $s_1=-1,s_2=-2,s_3=-3$, and in general, $s_n=-n$.  But then $(s_n)$ does not converge, and by the definition given to me I have to conclude that the limit superior does not exist.

Am I confused somewhere?

Comment: You're right, is that a homework question? $x_n$ must be bounded above and must not converge to $-\infty$.

Comment: Did you miss the $\sup$ in the definition of $s_n$?

Comment: It is a homework question.  I am going to speak with the professor about it when he is in his office.

Comment: user66091 I did miss the sup.  I fixed it now.

Comment: Yes. As a general comment, we sometimes say that the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ always exist, but then we must allow $\pm \infty$ as valid answers.

Comment: As you've shown, the problem isn't stated quite right.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $s_n:=\sup\{x_m:m\geq n\}$ is non-increasing.

To see this just notice that if $n\le k$, then $\{x_m \colon m\geq n\}\supseteq\{x_m \colon m\geq k\}$ and thus $s_n=\sup \{x_m  \colon  m\geq n\} \ge x_k = \{x_m  \colon m\geq k\}$.

Every bounded monotone sequence is convergent. See, for example, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).

<s>If the sequence is not bounded below, then so is the sequence $(s_n)$. So in this case we get $\limsup x_n = \lim s_n = -\infty$.</s>

If we allow limit also to be $\pm\infty$, then very monotone sequence has either finite limit or limit equal to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. So we can say that *every* sequence (without any condition on boundedness) has limit superior, if we *allow also $\pm\infty$*.

You are correct in saying that your example $x_n=-n$ does not have a finite limit superior. (And, as you write in [your comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125217/confused-about-this-definition-of-limit-superior/1125491?noredirect=1#comment2308939_1125491), the same is true whenever $\lim x_n=-\infty$.

Comment: $s_n$ may be bounded below even if $x_n$ is not bounded below. We only get $\limsup x_n = \lim s_n = -\infty$ when $x_n$ itself converges to $-\infty$.

Comment: @PedroM. You are correct, I made a total blunder there. Thanks for notifying me. (And it also seems to me that I might have misunderstood questions.)